# HTML Table - vertical line on change of a <th> tag

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a vertical line running down the whole length of a table on the change of a `<th>` tag. For example in the table below

[image]

How can I add a vertical line running from top to bottom between each month using CSS?

Comment: Maybe. Post the HTML and CSS you have in your question.

Comment: Is this table dynamically generated or you created it by hand ?

Comment: It's only just started, but as much as possible will be created but hand to reduce the processing required to generate it each time. (I am new to this so it may not be the right way to do it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what HTML you've got for your table, but here is an example. Use this code to add a vertical border.

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr { border: none; }
.line {
  border-left:  solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="line">Persons</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="line">Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">James</td>
    <td>Bond</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">Clark</td>
    <td>Kent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This solution is not quite right as it it draws a vertical line after every day in the column. Sorry if I wasn't clear but there are 2 row of table headers, the month name and the individual days. I need a vertical line only after the month changes, not after each day